# AVR external interrupt triggering by the falling edge: for how long should I keep signal low to guarantee triggering?

Tags: avr, atmega, interrupts, datasheet, gpio-external-interrupt

The question header appeared to bee too long. I'm sorry for that.

So I have a schematic generating a short LOW on INT0 pin of ATmega48PA. From the simulation I figured out that the LOW level will be there for about 800 ns. I plan to clock the AVR from internal RC with 1:8 divider which means 1 MHz Fosc.

How do I make sure that the interrupt will be triggered?

I make some reading of the datasheet but I was looking in a wrong chapters or there is no such information.

Could you please point me into the right direction to find needed info?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the datasheet, for the description of `ISC11`, `ISC10`:

> If edge or toggle interrupt is selected, pulses that last
>   longer than one clock period will generate an interrupt. Shorter pulses are not guaranteed to generate an interrupt.
>   If low level interrupt is selected, the low level must be held until the completion of the currently executing instruction
>   to generate an interrupt.

Since a 1MHz clock means that the 800ns interrupt pulse will last less than 1 cycle, the interrupt will not be generated reliably. The longest AVR instruction requires 4 cycles, so using a minimum clock of 6MHz will ensure that you catch all interrupts while the chip is active.

Comment: As I understand from the quotation edge triggering interrupt not requiring instruction to be executed. So I'd say that in my particular case I will need to increase the low level for 1000 ns to guarantee the interrupt. Right?

Comment: If you switch to falling-edge triggering, yes.